# How should Qt addin be fixed with added Qt files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-studio-addins

I use MS Visual Studio 2010, Qt 4.7.3, Qt addin 1.1.11.
I've added ui,cpp and h files from Qt Designer.
But the addin does not add custom build steps for them. The older gui forms worked well within that project. I've met the answers which concern manual adding custom build steps - UIC'ing and MOC'ing.
But I want to fix addin behavior.
What are the correct steps of adding ui,h, cpp files of some Qt widget to some existing Qt project?

Comment: By the way, when I created another Qt project (template was added by addin) with empty window, the addin was able to add custom build step for the same ui file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use qtcreator. Your will love it.

Comment: Is it possible to use VS Studio 2010 compiler and debugger from this IDE?